# Wiring a timer for a fan with No neutral wire

Tags: electrical, switch, fans, timer

Ok.  I can’t figure it out.  I’m on my third timer switch, this one not requiring a neutral.  When I hook it up to the fan stays on and none of the timer buttons are operable.  Please see the below pics for reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well…the black lead has current.  The white lead does not.

Comment: how did you hook it up that it didn't work? And please post a pic for the left wires from a different angle so we can see what that other wire nut in the back is for.

Comment: What make and model is the timer in question?

Comment: The other nut in the back is ground.  Black to black and red to white is how I hooked it up.  It’s always on the timer doesn’t work.  The timer is an Eaton no neutral timer I found on amazon.

Comment: It’s an Eaton pt18m.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you have there is a switch leg from the fan. That's not going to play well with the switch. You could use the ground on the other switch as a "boot leg neutral", but that's not code legal anymore. A few years ago I helped a friend install a bathroom fan that only had a switch leg to the box controlling the fan.  I used a totally mechanical timer that needed  no neutral. I worked great.   Hope this helps.

Comment: "but that's not code legal anymore". The wiring is grandfathered of course (neutral required at switch), but does  that not allow the OP to wire a neutral to the ground for a replacement switch? Also, if OP has few other timers or smart switches, wouldn't you say it would still be safe anyway?

Comment: I mentally divide electrical work into 3 categories: 1) not safe and not  up to code, 2) Safe,  but not up to current code and 3) Safe and up to code.   Bootlegging a ground as a neutral used to be OK, I can't remember which NEC version ruled it out. I may get snipped for this, but it's pretty safe bc the electronics in timers use virtually no power.  It may mess with up-stream GFCI outlets or breaker.   DANG....EDIT:  Bootlegging a ground is ONLY SAFE for tiny amounts of current, like the amount used by smart switches.   It's not safe for real loads.

Comment: Bootlegging neutral off ground has never been legal, so it isn't grandfathered.  Ever. Certain smart switches have UL permission to do that, but only under very restricted rules that assure no possibility of fatality.  You can only do that when the UL-approved device's instructions tell you to.  *Since UL allows it when it's safe, you can take to the bank that if UL didn't allow it, it's not safe*.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Good point on UL approval for using a boot legged ground as neutral.  I kinda tried to say that (tiny currents),  but didn't get my point across very well. Thanks for chiming in.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to wire in an electronic timer switch that needs a hot and neutral to power the electronics why not use a spring wound switch to power the fan. You can buy these switches at most big box stores or hardware outlets. Brand names Intermatic and Precision come to mind and cost about $20.00.

Comment: agreed d.george while old fashioned, mechanical timers are a good solution for switch legs that are missing a proper neutral.

Comment: Great suggestions thank you.  Been toying with the idea of the intematic for weeks, but was holding out hope for a digital solution.  Still on the fence.  Mechanical timers aren’t robust?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your insights and comments.  Perhaps Amazon needs to qc it’s timers.  Just got back from the hardware store, put in a single pole timer switch.  It works.  Done here.

Comment: So it's news to you that almost every electrical product on Amazon is dangerous junk that is illegal to even sell in the US?  Amazon listings include "Amazon Marketplace" which is third party sellers - basically eBay, and is flooded with *el cheapo* junk off Alibaba.   Legal equipment here has a UL, CSA or ETL listing, which are independent testing labs.